# Simple Algebra Question on the system $x - 2y = 6,\;ax + y = 4$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm having difficulty understanding this problem from Brilliant's course on Linear Algebra. Here is the text:

---

> Let's write down the general system: $$x - 2y = 6,\quad\quad ax + y = 4,$$ where $a$ is some real number. Try solving by taking $a$ times the first equation, minus the second. This gives: $$(-2a - 1)y = 6a - 4.$$

---

I don't understand how the left side of this equation is being constructed. Particularly, I'm lost as to how we end up with $-2a$, and even more lost as to where the $-1$ has come from.

It's been 25 years since I took Algebra I.

Comment: Did you follow the advice written? "Try solving by taking "a" times the first equation minus the second."

Comment: An easier way to solve would be to instead multiply the second equation by $2$ and then add to get $(1+2a)x=14$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two equations $x - 2y=6$ and $ax + y = 4$. If you multiply the first equation by $a$ both sides you get $a(x - 2y)=6a$ which is $ax - 2ay=6a$. Now subtract the second equation from this one to get

\begin{align}  
ax - 2ay&=6a \\  
-ax - y &= -4
\\-----&-----\\
-2ay-y&=6a-4
\end{align}

Now factor $y$ from the left side  to get $(-2a-1)y=6a-4.$

Comment: This is the answer. I did not know what factoring was.